# Thorough Mathematical intro to "computer 'science'" ...

Tags: education, computational-mathematics

Thorough Mathematical intro to “computer 'science'” ... [on hold]

Comment: Have you taken a look at several books, say on Amazon, with Math anc programming? There are a couple of them.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for the [Math Education SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm impressed with these people, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Euler

Comment: @Will Jagy: Thank you!!!

Comment: @orangeskid: as I said "I have searched deep and wide". What would be such books on amazon to you?

Comment: @Xander Henderson: Generally speaking, what do high school Math educators actually care/know about Math as a science?

Comment: @AlbretchMüller (1) The Math Eduction section of the site is not only (or even primarily) focused on high school level eduction.  (2) You have edited your post from the original version, which was much more about teaching.

Answer (score 2):

Just because it's fundamental doesn't make it elementary, or all mathematicians would begin with Zermelo-Fraenkel! A couple points:

- You can't teach a kid, or anyone, the same way you teach a computer. There needs to be motivation. If you start with computability theory and algebraic data types, it becomes, "Why do I need this to make Minecraft mods?"
- You risk demotivating your student. Teaching it the "right way" not only shelters the student from making mistakes (a necessary part of learning), but also makes it look like programming is dull, non-innovative, and "solved".
- I take exception to your premises. Positive reinforcement has existed for all time, not just for "kids nowadays." You also don't seem to know the first thing about computer science, as it is "no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes." You also seem to have some very interesting generalizations about certain professions and their competence.

If you still disagree, and you really want to teach this student the "right way", start with Haskell, notably "[Learn you a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)". You'll then want to teach them about how its type class system relates to Category Theory; Bartosz Milewski has an excellent video series on this. You'll have your depressed student writing unintelligible code in no time (geologically speaking).

Comment: Did I say people can learn without motivation? They say: "each generation needs there own music"(, games, ... and what they consider to be "music", "games", ...) I wonder what makes your Haskell book the "right way" to teach Math & CS. I am thinking of a basic high school/common core aligned book for kids not to get lost in it, keep a relevant reference to the Math they are being taught.